# Python "Can't Assign to Function Call" Meaning

Tags: python

My program was running fine the day before. Today when I was running it again, I keep getting the "can't assign to function call" error. This is happening on not only this code but my other programs as well. Could someone please help me, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

My code (its a background):

```
startBackground = (
Rect(0, 0, 400, 400, fill='aqua', opacity = 40, visible = False),
Label('Paint Plus', 193, 50, fill= 'gray', opacity= 40, bold = True, size =60, visible = False),
Label('Paint Plus', 200, 50, fill= 'red', opacity= 80, bold = True, size =60, border= 'white', borderWidth=2, visible = False),

## wooden part of brush
Polygon(40, 400, 40, 378, 43, 363, 46, 352, 55, 352, 58, 363, 62, 378, 62, 400, fill = 'saddleBrown', visible = False),
Polygon(40, 400, 40, 378, 43, 363, 47, 352, 48, 352, 45, 363, 42, 378, 42, 400, fill='black', opacity=30, visible = False),
Polygon(55, 353, 58, 363, 62, 378, 62, 400, 58, 400, 58, 378, 54, 363, 51, 352, fill='burlyWood', opacity=50, visible = False),

Polygon(114, 400, 114, 378, 117, 363, 120, 352, 129, 352, 132, 363, 136, 378, 136, 400, fill = 'saddleBrown', visible = False),
Polygon(114, 400, 114, 378, 117, 363, 121, 352, 122, 352, 119, 363, 116, 378, 116, 400, fill='black', opacity=30, visible = False),
Polygon(129, 353, 132, 363, 136, 378, 136, 400, 132, 400, 132, 378, 128, 363, 125, 352, fill='burlyWood', opacity=50, visible = False),

Polygon(188, 400, 188, 378, 191, 363, 194, 352, 203, 352, 206, 363, 210, 378, 210, 400, fill = 'saddleBrown', visible = False),
Polygon(188, 400, 188, 378, 191, 363, 195, 352, 196, 352, 193, 363, 190, 378, 190, 400, fill='black', opacity=30), visible = False,
Polygon(203, 353, 206, 363, 210, 378, 210, 400, 206, 400, 206, 378, 202, 363, 199, 352, fill='burlyWood', opacity=50, visible = False),

Polygon(262, 400, 262, 378, 265, 363, 268, 352, 277, 352, 280, 363, 284, 378, 284, 400, fill = 'saddleBrown', visible = False),
Polygon(262, 400, 262, 378, 265, 363, 269, 352, 270, 352, 267, 363, 264, 378, 264, 400, fill='black', opacity=30, visible = False),
Polygon(277, 353, 280, 363, 284, 378, 284, 400, 280, 400, 280, 378, 276, 363, 273, 352, fill='burlyWood', opacity=50, visible = False),

Polygon(336, 400, 336, 378, 339, 363, 342, 352, 351, 352, 354, 363, 358, 378, 358, 400, fill = 'saddleBrown', visible = False),
Polygon(336, 400, 336, 378, 339, 363, 343, 352, 344, 352, 341, 363, 338, 378, 338, 400, fill='black', opacity=30, visible = False),
Polygon(351, 353, 354, 363, 358, 378, 358, 400, 354, 400, 354, 378, 350, 363, 347, 352, fill='burlyWood', opacity=50, visible = False),

## metal part
Polygon(46, 352, 55, 352, 53.5, 338.5, 48, 338.5, fill='lightGray', visible = False),
Polygon(55, 352, 54, 339, 53, 339, 54, 352, fill='white', opacity=85, visible = False),

Polygon(120, 352, 129, 352, 127.5, 338.5, 122, 338.5, fill='lightGray', visible = False),
Polygon(129, 352, 128, 339, 127, 339, 128, 352, fill='white', opacity=85, visible = False),

Polygon(194, 352, 203, 352, 201.5, 338.5, 196, 338.5, fill = 'lightGray', visible = False),
Polygon(203, 352, 202, 339, 201, 339, 202, 352, fill='white', opacity=85, visible = False),

Polygon(268, 352, 277, 352, 275.5, 338.5, 270, 338.5, fill='lightGray', visible = False),
Polygon(277, 352, 276, 339, 275, 339, 276, 352, fill='white', opacity=85, visible = False),

Polygon(342, 352, 351, 352, 349.5, 338.5, 344, 338.5, fill='lightGray', visible = False),
Polygon(351, 352, 350, 339, 349, 339, 350, 352, fill='white', opacity=85, visible = False),

## brush part
Polygon(48, 339, 54, 339, 65, 329, 68, 322, 70, 316, 71, 305, 67, 295, 64, 290, 63, 289, 49, 270, 36, 280, 28, 292, 25, 305, 25, 311,31, 322, 48, 339, fill='brown', visible = False),
Polygon(48, 339, 54, 339, 65, 329, 68, 322, 70, 316, 71, 305, 67, 295, 64, 290, 63, 289, 49, 270, 36, 280, 28, 292, 25, 305, 25, 311,31, 322, 48, 339, fill='black', opacity=59, visible = False),
Polygon(49, 270, 63, 289, 64, 290, 67, 295, 71, 305, 70, 316, 68, 322, 65, 329, 54, 339, 51, 339, 60, 329, 64, 322, 66, 316, 67, 305, 63, 295, 59, 289, 46, 270, fill='white', opacity=35, visible = False),

Polygon(122, 339, 128, 339, 139, 329, 142, 322, 144, 316, 145, 305, 141, 295, 138, 290, 137, 289, 123, 270, 110, 280, 102, 292, 99, 305, 99, 311, 105, 322, 122, 339, fill='brown', visible = False),
Polygon(122, 339, 128, 339, 139, 329, 142, 322, 144, 316, 145, 305, 141, 295, 138, 290, 137, 289, 123, 270, 110, 280, 102, 292, 99, 305, 99, 311, 105, 322, 122, 339, fill='black', opacity=59, visible = False),
Polygon(123, 270, 137, 289, 138, 290, 141, 295, 145, 305, 144, 316, 142, 322, 139, 329, 128, 339, 125, 339, 134, 329, 138, 322, 140, 316, 141, 305, 137, 295, 133, 289, 120, 270, fill='white', opacity=35, visible = False),

Polygon(196, 339, 202, 339, 213, 329, 216, 322, 218, 316, 219, 305, 215, 295, 212, 290, 211, 289, 197, 270, 184, 280, 176, 292, 173, 305, 173, 311, 179, 322, 196, 339, fill='brown', visible = False),
Polygon(196, 339, 202, 339, 213, 329, 216, 322, 218, 316, 219, 305, 215, 295, 212, 290, 211, 289, 197, 270, 184, 280, 176, 292, 173, 305, 173, 311, 179, 322, 196, 339, fill='black', opacity=59, visible = False),
Polygon(197, 270, 211, 289, 212, 290, 215, 295, 219, 305, 218, 316, 216, 322, 213, 329, 202, 339, 199, 339, 208, 329, 212, 322, 214, 316, 215, 305, 211, 295, 207, 289, 194, 270, fill='white', opacity=35, visible = False),

Polygon(270, 339, 276, 339, 287, 329, 290, 322, 292, 316, 293, 305, 289, 295, 286, 290, 285, 289, 271, 270, 258, 280, 250, 292, 247, 305, 247, 311, 253, 322, 270, 339, fill='brown', visible = False),
Polygon(270, 339, 276, 339, 287, 329, 290, 322, 292, 316, 293, 305, 289, 295, 286, 290, 285, 289, 271, 270, 258, 280, 250, 292, 247, 305, 247, 311, 253, 322, 270, 339, fill='black', opacity=59, visible = False),
Polygon(271, 270, 285, 289, 286, 290, 289, 295, 293, 305, 292, 316, 290, 322, 287, 329, 276, 339, 273, 339, 282, 329, 286, 322, 288, 316, 289, 305, 285, 295, 281, 289, 268, 270, fill='white', opacity=35, visible = False),

Polygon(344, 339, 350, 339, 361, 329, 364, 322, 366, 316, 367, 305, 363, 295, 360, 290, 359, 289, 345, 270, 332, 280, 324, 292, 321, 305, 321, 311, 327, 322, 344, 339, fill='brown', visible = False),
Polygon(344, 339, 350, 339, 361, 329, 364, 322, 366, 316, 367, 305, 363, 295, 360, 290, 359, 289, 345, 270, 332, 280, 324, 292, 321, 305, 321, 311, 327, 322, 344, 339, fill='black', opacity=59, visible = False),
Polygon(345, 270, 359, 289, 360, 290, 363, 295, 367, 305, 366, 316, 364, 322, 361, 329, 350, 339, 347, 339, 356, 329, 360, 322, 362, 316, 363, 305, 359, 295, 355, 289, 442, 270, fill='white', opacity=35, visible = False),

## paint part on brush
Polygon(47, 268, 37, 272, 27, 285, 25, 296, 25, 309, 25, 311, 27, 323, 28, 325, 32, 330, 40, 321, 49, 310, 54, 299, 57, 290, 59, 289, 61, 283, fill='yellow', visible = False),
Polygon(45, 274, 34, 281, 31, 288, 28, 299, 35, 299, 43, 289, 45, 282, fill='white', opacity=85, visible = False),

Polygon(121, 268, 111, 272, 101, 285, 99, 296, 99, 309, 99, 311, 101, 323, 102, 325, 106, 330, 114, 321, 123, 310, 128, 299, 131, 290, 133, 289, 135, 283, fill='blue', visible = False),
Polygon(119, 274, 108, 281, 105, 288, 101, 299, 109, 299, 117, 289, 119, 282, fill='white', opacity=85, visible = False),

Polygon(195, 268, 185, 272, 175, 285, 173, 296, 173, 309, 173, 311, 175, 323, 176, 325, 180, 330, 188, 321, 197, 310, 202, 299, 205, 290, 207, 289, 209, 283, fill='red', visible = False),
Polygon(193, 274, 182, 281, 179, 288, 175, 299, 183, 299, 191, 289, 193, 282, fill='white', opacity=85, visible = False),

Polygon(269, 268, 259, 272, 249, 285, 247, 296, 247, 309, 247, 311, 247, 323, 250, 325, 254, 330, 262, 321, 271, 310, 276, 299, 279, 290, 281, 289, 283, 283, fill='green', visible = False),
Polygon(267, 274, 256, 281, 253, 288, 249, 299, 257, 299, 265, 289, 267, 282, fill='white', opacity=85, visible = False),

Polygon(343, 268, 333, 272, 323, 285, 321, 296, 321, 309, 321, 311, 321, 323, 324, 325, 328, 330, 336, 321, 345, 310, 350, 299, 353, 290, 355, 289, 357, 283, fill='darkOrange', visible = False),
Polygon(341, 274, 330, 281, 327, 288, 323, 299, 331, 299, 339, 289, 341, 282, fill='white', opacity=85, visible = False))
```

I do have a closing ')' at the end of the last line to match the very first one

Comment: Which lines is pointed by the error ?

Comment: 8th Polygon ; `)` is not at the end of the line, Iguess you don't use an IDE because it sould have show you where (even repl online https://repl.it/repls/StridentLuxuriousSnake)

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be a misplaced parenthesis.

line 16 has a parenthesis after "opacity=30" which probably should be after "visible = False".

Here's the line with the change:

```
Polygon(188, 400, 188, 378, 191, 363, 195, 352, 196, 352, 193, 363, 190, 378, 190, 400, fill='black', opacity=30, visible = False),
```

Hope that fixes the issue :)

Comment: Please don't answer such typo, just flag it, thanks (because this will help no one else)

Comment: If I still want to help answer the person's question, should I just do it in the comments then?

Comment: Exactly but you may wait to have enough reputation ;)